# What will be the pictorial diagram of this transition table?

Tags: finite-automata

I was doing my homework and I am confused on what I'm doing, it can't be that straightforward. I'm making a mistake somewhere. I tried looking for practice problems but they don't cover my issue either, I'm still confused. What will be the pictorial diagram for the following transition table?

[image: a table consisting in four columns and three rows]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just create a super simple [Graphviz](//graphviz.org) document encoding the information:

```
$ cat foo.gv 
digraph {
  q0 -> q0 [label = "input: a\noutput: 0"];
  q0 -> q2 [label = "input: b\noutput: 0"];
  q1 -> q1 [label = "input: a\noutput: 1"];
  q1 -> q0 [label = "input: b\noutput: 1"];
  q2 -> q2 [label = "input: a\noutput: 1"];
  q2 -> q1 [label = "input: b\noutput: 1"];
}
$ _
```

Process it:

```
$ dot foo.gv -T png -o foo.png
$ echo $?
0
$ _
```

Profit!

[image: foo.png]

Comment: Hey is this the moore diagram?

Comment: @Ammar, hey, so you know for the future, we are encouraging gender-neutral writing: see https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334900/160917, https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/335031/160917.  I hope you'll consider thinking about how you can follow those guidelines!

Comment: I'm sorry but is that a warning? I didn't even know I'm violating any guidelines and there isn't even any mention of a gender pronoun like he/she so how come?

Comment: [This comment](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/115744/what-will-be-the-pictorial-diagram-of-this-transition-table/115746?noredirect=1#comment244930_115746) now marked with "this comment was edited 1 time" wasn't gender neutral in its original form, and so was flagged for moderation attention.